# What is the "TBD Release Iron" and what are the modifications?

Tags: winapi, numa

Some Win32 API function documentation (for example [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getlogicalprocessorinformationex) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getnumanodeprocessormask)) contains the following note:

> Starting with **TBD Release Iron**, the behavior of this and other NUMA
> functions has been modified to better support systems with nodes
> containing more that 64 processors. For more information about this
> change, including information about enabling the old behavior of this
> API, see NUMA Support.

1. What exactly is the "TBD Release Iron"?
2. Which Windows versions does it support?
3. What modifications does the note refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elsewhere, for example on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/numa-support, it's called

> Windows 10 Build 20348

In the same note.

So it looks like the folks at <strike>MSDN</strike> <strike>MS Docs</strike> Learn have some mass replacing to do.

As for the actual change, there now are (as is tradition) `Ex` methods for NUMA that add support for processor groups, allowing you to specify affinity for more applications running on machines with more than 64 logical processors, if I interpret it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

"To Be Determined (TBD) release" means Microsoft has not decided exactly when this feature is going to be shipped. Iron is a branch codename. According to [Betawiki](https://betawiki.net/wiki/Iron), Iron was 21H1 and included Windows Server 2022.

Why Microsoft expects people to keep up with their internal codenames and if the changes have shipped and they just forgot to update the page to use the publuc name **or** if the feature/change has not shipped yet, I don't know.

The changes as compared with Windows 7 are listed under "Behavior starting with TBD Release Iron" on each page...

Comment: What modifications does the note refer to?

Comment: On which page? For GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx, RelationNumaNode changed and RelationNumaNodeEx was added...